# Spring boot connection with mysql workbecnch

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I created a spring boot maven project using STS eclipse
In application.properties

```
    spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/crud
    spring.datasource.username = root
    spring.datasource.password = root
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

I created Player entity class, then I run the project but in my workbench there is no table created. Is that because spring boot not connect with db? Then how can I overcome this problem.
This is my pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is player Entity

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "PLAYER")
    public class Player {
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
       @Column(name = "PLAYER_ID")
       private int id;
       @Column(name = "PLAYER_NAME")
       private String playerName;

       public int getId() {
          return id;
       }
       public void setId(int id) {
          this.id = id;
       }
       public String getPlayerName() {
          return playerName;
       }
       public void setPlayerName(String playerName) {
          this.playerName = playerName;
       }

     }
```

Comment: Please post also the Player entity classe

Comment: @Michel Foucault added!

Comment: Any error when run the project

Comment: No thats the big issue

Comment: If  you've some some errors in the log, please post them too

Comment: https://ibb.co/P9n5QHK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you didn't create the Database. 
You try to create the database or replace the connection string with the following:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/crud?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

**UPDATE**

Please add the following dependency in your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and delete the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: No, I created schema but for the test, I deleted it and replaced your code, but it didn't create crud database

Comment: After that dependency, I' getting an error https://ibb.co/P9n5QHK